# How do I make multiple consecutive reads on a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tls1.2

Currently, I am trying to handle a TLS connection in C++. I have already successfully written the Client Hello in the socket, however I am having trouble reading from the socket.

```
// poll until server hello is received
int len = 0;
while (len == 0) {
    ioctl(sockfd, FIONREAD, &len);
}

uint8_t server_hello[len];
if (read(sockfd, server_hello, len) < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to read server hello");
};

// poll until server cert is received
len = 0;
while (len == 0) {
    ioctl(sockfd, FIONREAD, &len);
}

uint8_t server_cert[len];
if (read(sockfd, server_cert, len) < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to read server cert");
};
```

The first server_hello read works fine, but I do not know how to "clear" the socket and wait for the server_cert read. I haven't been able to find too much info on this and have no idea where to look for resource on this.

Comment: Why do you want to "clear" the socket?  What does it mean to "clear" a socket?

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner read() is returning the same output twice, when called twice, how do I clear the buffer which the packet is stored in and read the second packet?

Comment: It probably isn’t returning the same output twice; rather it’s returning the number of bytes it wrote into your buffer, but you aren’t looking at how many bytes it actually wrote, but instead assuming it wrote the same number of bytes as what you asked for.  Then when you look at the contents of the buffer you see some if the old bytes still in it because they weren’t overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple fundamental issues with the shown code.

```
int len = 0;
while (len == 0) {
    ioctl(sockfd, FIONREAD, &len);
}
```

This kind of an approach will peg the CPU to 100% load, in a busy loop, until there's data on the socket. This is the first issue; however it's a moot point, for the reasons that will be described in a moment. This will accomplish absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever, due to other fundamental issues with the shown code. You will end up deleting this code entirely, after understanding what all the issues are.

```
uint8_t server_hello[len];
```

This is not valid C++, you are using a non-standard C++ extension from your compiler. Many C++ compilers will refuse to compile this. In C++ the sizes of all arrays are compile-time constants. They cannot be set with a variable, like this.

This is also a moot point, and this also will end up being removed, in the end. This approach will not work anyway, for the following reason:

```
read(sockfd, server_hello, len)
```

This will not work fundamentally. The apparent intent of the shown code is that it expects to receive two discrete TLS "packets" from the socket. The shown code apparently expects both packets to come as two discrete `read()`s, and for these purposes it attempts to figure out the size of the packets, in advance, in the above shown manner, using the historic `FIONREAD` ioctl.

Unfortunately, sockets do not work like this on a fundamental level. This should be explained, fully, in your network programming textbook.

Just to simplify: let's say that your server sent those two packets, and the first one was 20 bytes long, and the second packet was 40 bytes long, for the sake of this description. The actual sizes don't matter.

Rule #1 of socket programming: you have absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, what any `read()`, or `write()` will do for you. The only thing you're guaranteed is that `read()` or `write()` will return the number of bytes read or written. When either reading, and writing, you have no guarantees, of any kind, on the number of bytes that are read or written, except that it won't be more than the size of the buffer that's specified by the third parameter (or it can be an error).

So, in this case, the very first `read()` from your socket can return any number between 1 and 60. You have no control over it, whatsoever.

If both packets are already received by the time your first `read()` call, your first `read()` call will return all 60 bytes. Here you are. Enjoy your meal. This is most likely the behavior you're observing, the TLS server optimizes its own socket logic to spit both packets in one `write()` call, and you end up getting a single bag with both goodies.

But if the server's packets got fragmented, the first `read()` call might tell you that you got the first 10 bytes of the first 20-byte packet. Your second `read()`, perhaps, will return the second 10 bytes of the first packet, and maybe a couple of bytes from the 2nd packet, returning 12.

This is how all TCP sockets work. There are no options to adjust `read()`s behavior. That's how `read()` works with sockets.

And this is why the clumsy `FIONREAD`-based approach is not merely a flawed approach that spins the CPU at 100%, but it also accomplishes nothing useful at all whatsoever. Sure, you'll know as soon as there 1 byte, or more, available on the socket. So what? You can't make any assumptions about how many bytes that's going to be available to read, from the socket, anyway. You might as well just declare a large buffer, `read()` whatever there's to `read()` on the socket, and then move on. You'll have to do it anyway, you have no choice.

> I do not know how to "clear" the socket

That's because there's no such thing. A socket is a hole in sky from which bytes fall, whenever they feel like it falling.

In order for your code to be robust and reliably read from sockets, all code that reads from sockets must implement the appropriate logic to read and parse the data from the socket logically, whenever it appears. In this case, appropriate logic must be written to read from the socket enough bytes to determine the size of each TLS packet, from its metadata, then keep reading the exact number of bytes that comprises the packet. It might end up reading more, the start of next TLS packet, together with the current one. The code must handle this correctly, process the TLS packet, and then start stitching together the next TLS packet, that it got a head start on, already. And so on.

All of that must be implemented in code, and logic. Based on your description you appear to try to implement TLS yourself, so it's entirely on your shoulders to do all this work.

By the way, all of this also applies to writing to the socket too. The code that writes the *ClientHello* packet is not shown, but it can't assume that however many bytes it `write()`s to the socket will actually be written, as well. Every TCP socket in the world reserves every right to reject the number of bytes that attempted to be `write`()n to it, with `write()`'s return value indicating how many bytes were actually written. If less than requested, it's on you to try again, to write whatever's left.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. I have one question though. If sockets are simply “a hole in the sky” then why am I getting the same data in both the read calls?

Comment: Maybe because they're not? Only the first handful of bytes is the same and it only looks that way? This is fairly common with highly complex wire protocols like TLS. In any case without debugging and tracing the syscalls with `strace` it's not possible to give an authoritative explanation. The only authoritative statement that can be given about the shown code are the described logical flaws.